# git pre-push hook doesn't work with visual studio git interface

Tags: .net, bash, visual-studio, nunit, githooks

I have created a pre-push hook that runs all the unit tests (NUint) if a project that contains the string "NDI" has changed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current branch
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

# Get the remote repository and branch
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote)
remote_branch=$(git config --get branch.$branch.merge | sed 's#^refs/heads/##')

# Check if any project containing "NDI" in its name has changed
if git diff --name-only $remote/$remote_branch HEAD | grep -q "NDI"; then
  # Run all NUnit tests
  dotnet test
fi

# If the tests failed, cancel the push
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Tests failed. Push cancelled."
  exit 1
fi
```

The problem is when I try to use the visual studio git interface to push the new code to the remote repository I get the error message: *"Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details."* 
 The output window doesn't have any special message about the problem, just about the successful build from the commit. When I try to use the VS terminal with `git push` it does work and runs the unit tests successfully if an NDI project has changed. 
 Side note: it works as expected for the pre-commit hook.

Comment: Try to debug the problem with a pre-push hook like `echo test hook stdout; echo test hook stderr >&2; exit 1` and see if any of its output shows up in the output window.

Comment: i have tried that, it doesn't output anything

Comment: Good to know. Then I'm pretty sure the problem is on the VS side; nothing I can help you with, sorry.  Edit: There is already this [bug report from 2018 (unresolved but closed)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-integration-does-not-show-local-hooks-output/153462).

Comment: *Closed - Lower Priority* ...

Comment: seems like they threw it under the bus

Answer (score 1):

As of today, it is accepted that this is a bug and it is currently under Microsoft's consideration to be fixed. The decision to fix the bug will depend on the number of people affected by the issue. 
In the meantime, it is recommended to try workaround solutions or "follow and vote on that problem ticket" - Microsoft, in order to help prioritize a fix.
Link to the problem on the forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Failed-to-push-to-the-remote-repository/10238402 
I will try to keep this answer updated.

Comment: Did you manage to have a workaround to this @Tiran? I am using it fine in the terminal and other IDEs. I would like to get it working in VS as the whole company has been using VS for development and changing that will cause friction.